# How to get Swiper instance from getSwiper in Ionic5 and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, swiper.js

I am using `ion-slides` in my Ionic 5 project in Angular. As per [this document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) I want to get the instance of the Swiper by method `getSwiper` to use [Zoom Methods & Properties](https://swiperjs.com/api/#zoom)

Following is the HTML code:

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" zoom>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
      <img [src]=myURL />
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

I am not able to call the method `getSwiper` in the class. I don't know how to call it. Do I need to use `ViewChild` for `ion-slides` or any IonSlide event can get the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss'],
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(await this.slides.getSwiper())
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewChild as suggested by @ihorbond and you can also pass swiper using template reference at any of [the events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#events):

```
    <ion-slides #slider [options]="slideOpts" zoom (ionSlideDidChange)="slidesChanged(slider)">
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Then in your template:

```
  slidesChanged(slider) {
    slider.getActiveIndex().then(index=>{
      console.log(index)
    })
  }
```

Keeping in mind that [all ionSlides methods](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#methods) return promises.

Stackblits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-fsb1bx